# Hiding view not working - swift

Tags: ios, swift

Attached the Subviews hierarchy, I just want to hide one and show other after signin. I cannot use navigation controller as I need the swipe to be working inside webview.

So I tried simply toggling view but it is not consistent.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I am trying.

```
func openBrowserView() {
    loader.startAnimating()
    self.viewLoginForm.hidden = true
    self.viewDashboard.hidden = false
    print (" views hid")

    let requestURL = NSURL(string:browserURL)            
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)            
    request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod            
    webView.delegate = self;        
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more detail about what is happening than "it is not consistent" for someone to be able to help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) The syncing problem is usually because you are not updating UI on the main thread. Make sure that you make all UI changes on the main thread. Easy to fix, just use the code below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    loader.startAnimating()
    self.viewLoginForm.hidden = true
    self.viewDashboard.hidden = false
}
```

2) The other problem could be that the subview you are hiding and showing is still under some other view so you cannot see it. So simply bring the subview that you are showing to front.

```
self.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

Comment: this problem occurred in my case inside `viewDidLoad`, and I resolved it by using `DispatchQueue.main.async`. which is really weird since viewDidLoad is running in itself on the main thread. Any reason to it?

Answer (score 0):

A tiny improvement to Ankit Goel's answer.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
}
```

was showing me this error : "Ambiguous use of DispatchQueue on trying to use main thread"

So I instead used

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

})
```

reference : [Ambiguous use of DispatchQueue on trying to use main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644492/ambiguous-use-of-dispatchqueue-on-trying-to-use-main-thread)