# Ambiguous use of DispatchQueue on trying to use main thread

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, swift3, xcode8

This is a weird issue and I can't seem to find any help. On Swift 3, trying to make a call on the main thread I try to use DispatchQueue.main.async, but it doesn't compile.

Any ideas would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `DispatchQueue.main.async { print("foo") }` compiles without problems. Could you provide your full statement as code, not as screenshot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code instead, this is the Swift 3.0 syntax:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

})
```

#### For Swift 4.x you can also use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

}
```